# Ajax loop refresh on click

Tags: loop, ajax

I display a random post loop on a page. I'd like to put a "refresh" link to refresh the content of the loop via ajax.

Is this possible?

This is my loop if it helps:

```
            <ul id="content-inner" class="thumb-grid clearfix">
            <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=20&orderby=rand'); ?>
            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $my_image_url = get('thumbnail'); ?>" alt="" />
                        <span class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                        <span class="feat"><?php $articletags = strip_tags(get_the_tag_list('',', ',''));echo $articletags;?></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endwhile;?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't be too tricky. First: create a javascript file and add this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#refresh-links-id').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post(ajaxurl,{action:'jpb_random_loop'}, function(data){
      $('#content-inner').fadeOut(250).empty().append( data ).fadeIn(250);
    });
  });
});
```

Save that file in your theme directory somewhere (could be in a subdirectory too). For this to work, the refresh link should not be inside `ul#content-inner`. Pretty basic jQuery post call, though.

Next, add this to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function jpb_template_redirect(){
  if( <conditions under which this javascript should execute> ){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'random-loop', '<url to the javascript file above>', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0' );
  }
}

function jpb_random_loop_cb(){
  query_posts('posts_per_page=20&orderby=rand');
  if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <li>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
      <img src="<?php echo $my_image_url = get('thumbnail'); ?>" alt="" />
      <span class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
      <span class="feat"><?php $articletags = strip_tags(get_the_tag_list('',', ',''));echo $articletags;?></span>
      </a>
    </li>
  <?php endwhile; endif;
  die();
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'jpb_template_redirect' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_jpb_random_loop', 'jpb_random_loop_cb' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_jpb_random_loop', 'jpb_random_loop_cb' );
```

That will tie everything together. Just make sure the logic is correct in the `template_redirect` function so that the javascript is included in the right pages.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it doesn't seem to be working though. I assume the conditions part in the redirect function can be something like this "if(is_page('random'))" ? Ffurther more my image thumbnail (which uses the magicfields plugin) fails to load now the loop is put into that function... thanks for the effort

Comment: I also call it in the page via "<?php if(function_exists('jpb_random_loop_cb')) {jpb_random_loop_cb();}?>" i assume this is right ?

Comment: Yup, that'll work! And saves time, space, and sanity! :D

Comment: hey john, still having a rough time on this one.
why isn't "ajaxurl" defined? thanks for help.
--

Comment: as I see, ajaxurl is defined in the admin header. But i still get  "ajaxurl is not defined"  while using the code in my theme.

Comment: `ajaxurl` must be defined on non-admin page. adding `echo '<script>var adminurl = ' . admin_url( 'admin_ajax.php' ) . ';</script>';` to the `wp_head` hook should do it.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin seems like it would do what you are looking for.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-ajax-random-posts/

If you don't want to use the plugin you could always check out the code for the refresh link and try to get it to work for you.